# Fetch an XML node-name as regex in XSL Stylesheet transformation

Tags: java, regex, xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML (I know it is incorrect as per XML standards but I am restricted to changes as I am processing response from external party) as follows,

```
 XML Snippet : <root>
                 <3party>some_value</3party>
               </root>
```

I would like to fetch <3party> from above snippet in XSL stylesheet transformation. The fact is the <3party> element is invalid so I can no refer it as follows as it fails the xsl compilation. I would need a way to refer it as a partial element may be using some regx way? Following is incorrect.

```
   <xsl:variable select="$response/root/3party" />
```

Any answers would help me out.

Edit : Possible solution to above usecase would be.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$response/root">
    <!-- Node name -->
         <xsl:variable name="name" select="local-name()" />
     <!-- check if it contains party -->
         <xsl:if test="contains($name, 'party')">
             <!-- Node value -->
             <xsl:variable name="value" select="node()" />
         </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I found solution to this as follows,

Loop through all the XML nodes and use XSL function to check partial name. Edited my question with answer.

Comment: "I have an XML (I know it is incorrect as per XML standards but I am restricted to changes as I am processing response from external party)" - You don't have an XML. You have something weird. Don't try to use XML tools to process non-XML. Don't tag your questions XML when you are dealing with something that isn't XML.

Comment: @MichaelKay I am processing XML data in XSL transformation.

Comment: @TechBreak Your input is not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT. Find another tool. Or fix the tool that produces your input.

Comment: @MichaelKay I have given XML input and a working solution also. The XSL compilation is successful for me as well.

Comment: Your input contains an illegal tag name "3party" and your message suggests that you know it is not legal XML, so why are you now claiming that it is?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the code added to your question:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$response/root">
    <!-- Node name -->
         <xsl:variable name="name" select="local-name()" />
     <!-- check if it contains party -->
         <xsl:if test="contains($name, 'party')">
             <!-- Node value -->
             <xsl:variable name="value" select="node()" />
         </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The test `contains($name, 'party')` will **never** return true. The context node's name is `root` and "root" does not contain "party".

---

On a more general note: you seem to think that the problem is how to get your XSLT stylesheet to compile. That is not so. The real problem here is that your input is not well-formed XML. The input must be parsed before it can be transformed, and if it's not well-formed XML, the process will fail well before even considering your stylesheet.